# Isomorphism of direct sum of rings

Tags: ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Let $$ 0 \to_0R \to_i M \to_j N \to_0 0 $$ be a sequence of rings and homomorphisms such that $i$ is injective, $j$ is surjective and $im(i)=ker(j)$. Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $M \cong R \oplus N$ with $i : R \to R \oplus N$ and $ j : R \oplus N \to N$ the canonical homomorphisms;
> 2. There is a homomorphism $q : M \to R$ such that $q \circ i = 1$;
> 3. There is a homomorphism $ p : N \to M $ such that $j \circ p = 1 $;

I actually have couple of questions in my attempt:

**My Attempt:**

I am trying to prove the following implications : (1) $\implies$ (2), (2) $\implies$ (1), (1) $\implies$ (3) and (3) $\implies$ (1).

I am done with (1) $\implies$ (2) & (3). But while going backword, I stuck in the surjectivity part. For example, solving $ (2) \implies (1) $, I defined the map $$\phi : M \to R \oplus N$$ $$ \phi(m) = ( q(m),j(m) )$$ This map is well defined and homomorphism. I have also proved that it is injective, but while showing it is surjective, I stuck. For example, TO prove it is surjective, I need to show that for any $(r,n)$, there exist a $m \in M$ such that $\phi(m)=(r,n)$ i.e $ q(m)=r $ and $ j(m) = n $.

Now, since $j$ is surjective, so for every $n$, there exist a $m \in M$ such that $j(m)=n$, Now the problem is, I am unable to show that for the same $m$, $q(m)=r$ ??

In the implication $(3) \implies (1)$, I defined the following map (that looks the natural one) $$ \psi : R \oplus N \to M $$ $$ (r,n) \mapsto i(r) + p(n) $$

This map is weldefined. It preserves Addition but there is a problem in multiplication. **Am I defining the map in the right way??** This map is injective but again **I am confused at surjectivity part**.

**My Questions?**

1. How to prove the surjectivity of map $\phi$?
2. In $(3) \implies (1)$, is the map I defined would work for proving isomorphism? If so, then how to show it preserves multiplication?
3. The surjectivity of map $\psi$ ?

any kind of help would be really appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See [Why isn't there necessarily a direct sum of rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209200/why-isnt-there-necessarily-a-direct-sum-of-rings) and (for modules) [MacLane, *Homology*, p. 16](https://books.google.fr/books?id=pxRlrJn-WPgC&pg=PA16).