# Regarding Atiyah-Macdonald Chapter 3 Exercise 27 ii)

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

Let $B = \Pi_{\alpha} B_{\alpha}$ be the direct product of finitely many $A$-algebras $f_{\alpha}: A \to B_{\alpha}$. Then if $f: A \to B$ is given by $f(x) = (f_{\alpha}(x))_{\alpha}$ show that 
$$
f^*(\text{Spec}(B)) = \bigcup_{\alpha}f_{\alpha}^*(\text{Spec}(B))
$$

**My Proof:** With all tensors being over $A$ and letting $k$ be the residue field at a particular prime ideal $p \in \text{Spec}(A)$ we have that

\begin{align*}
f^{*-1}(p) &= \text{Spec}(B\otimes k) \\
&= \text{Spec}\left(\left(\bigoplus_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}\right)\otimes k\right) \\
&= \text{Spec}\left(\bigoplus_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}\otimes k\right) \\
&= \bigsqcup_{\alpha} \text{Spec} \left( B_{\alpha} \otimes k\right) \\
&= \bigsqcup_{\alpha} f_{\alpha}^{*-1}(p) \quad \quad (1)
\end{align*}

Thus we have that $f^{*-1}(p) \neq \varnothing \iff \exists \alpha \, \,, \, \, f_{\alpha}^{*-1}(p) \neq \varnothing $. This gives us that 
$$
f^*(\text{Spec}(B)) = \bigcup_{\alpha}f_{\alpha}^*(\text{Spec}(B))
$$

My only concern is that there is a disjoint union in eq (1). I was wondering whether this disjoint union is an external one rather than an internal one.

Thanks,
Vatsa

Comment: Why do you use the direct summand symbol $\bigoplus$ here? Do you mean to denote the product $\prod_α B_α$  here?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the direct product over a finite family of modules is the same as the direct sum. I used the direct summand symbol because there is a theorem in the book saying that finite direct sums "distribute" over a tensor product.

Comment: Stricty speaking, there is no such thing as a direct sum of rings, see Martin’s answer to [Is $A × B$ the same as $A \oplus B$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345501/is-a-times-b-the-same-as-a-oplus-b?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I get what you mean.

Comment: Thanks. I unknowingly swapped the categories I was working in. Ill keep this in mind in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apart from using “$\bigoplus$” instead of “$\prod$”, your proof is fine. The disjoint union is an external one.

However, your proof is unnecessarily abstract. Instead

- consider how primes in $\prod_α B_α$ exactly look like, and
- compare their preimages under $f$ to preimages of primes under $f_α$.

You will quickly find that every preimage of a prime under $f$ can be realised as a preimage of a prime under $f_α$ for some $α$ and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification