# Correct terminology for “commutative coproducts” and how to formalize them.

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be one of the concrete categories $\mathrm{Mon}$, $\mathrm{Alg}_$ or $\mathrm{Lie}_$ (for some commutative ring $$).

For any object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and any two elements $x$ and $y$ of $X$ have a notion of what it means for $x$ and $y$ commute.
As a consequence, we can say that two morphisms $f \colon X \to Z$ and $g \colon Y \to Z$ with common codomain “commute” if $f(x)$ commutes with $g(y)$ for all $x$, $y$.
This allows us to consider a kind of “commutative coproduct”:
an object $X ⨿_{\mathrm{com}} Y$ of $\mathcal{C}$ together with morphisms $X \to X ⨿_{\mathrm{com}} Y$ and $Y \to X ⨿_{\mathrm{com}} Y$ such that morphisms $X ⨿_{\mathrm{com}} Y \to Z$ correspond to pairs of commuting morphisms $X \to Z$ and $Y \to Z$.

The commutative coproduct is given by $M × N$ in $\mathrm{Mon}$, by $A ⊗_ B$ in $\mathrm{Alg}_$, and by $ ⊕ $ in $\mathrm{Lie}_$.
(I should maybe use the notation $M ⊕ N$ instead of $M × N$.)

**Question**

What is the correct terminology for “commutative coproducts”?
What kind of categorical framework is typically used to define and study them?

**Motivational example**

Let us denote the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra $$ by $\mathrm{U}()$.
It is kind of important that the functor $\mathrm{U}$ from $\mathrm{Lie}_$ to $\mathrm{Alg}_$ preserves commutative coproducts.
This is, for example, used in the construction of the bialgebra structure on $\mathrm{U}()$.

More explicitly, the commutative coproduct seems to give us a monoidal structure on each of the above categories $\mathcal{C}$.
Every Lie algebra $$ is a comonoid object in $(\mathrm{Lie}_, ⊕)$ via the diagonal map $ \to  ⊕ $ as comultiplication and map $ \to 0$ as counit.
The functor $\mathrm{U}$ from $(\mathrm{Lie}_, ⊕)$ to $(\mathrm{Alg}_, ⊗_)$ is strong monoidal, and so $\mathrm{U}()$ is a comonoid object in $(\mathrm{Alg}_, ⊗_)$, i.e., a bialgebra.

**Some random observations**

- Instead of only the three categories from above, one could also consider $\mathrm{Grp}$, $\mathrm{AbMon}$, $\mathrm{Ab}$, $\mathrm{CAlg}_$, …
  But in the “commutative categories” $\mathrm{AbMon}$, $\mathrm{Ab}$ and $\mathrm{CAlg}_$ all morphisms commute, whence the commutative coproduct is just the usual coproduct.
  The situation for $\mathrm{Grp}$ is probably best understood by looking at the larger category $\mathrm{Mon}$.
- Monoids are precisely the monoid objects in $(\mathrm{Set}, ×)$, and $$-algebras are precisely the monoid objects in $(\mathrm{Mod}_, ⊗_)$.
  I suspect we can more generally define for every symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{M}$ what it means for two morphisms $f \colon A \to M$ and $g \colon B \to M$ in $\mathrm{Mon}(\mathcal{M})$ to commute.
  (I suspect that we want the two resulting composites $A ⊗ B \to M ⊗ M \to M$ and $A ⊗ B \to B ⊗ A \to M ⊗ M \to M$ to agree.)
  However, I don’t think that the example $\mathrm{Lie}_$ arrives in this way.
- In $\mathrm{Mon}$ and $\mathrm{Lie}_$, the commutative coproduct agrees with the product.
  More explicitly, there exists a unique morphism from $X ⨿_{\mathrm{com}} Y$ to $X × Y$ resulting from the identity morphisms and zero morphisms via the universal properties,
  and this morphism is an isomorphism.
  If we were talking about usual coproducts instead of commutative coproducts, then this would lead us to the notion of biproducts.
- We always have a morphism from the coproduct $X ⨿ Y$ into the commutative coproduct $X ⨿_{\mathrm{com}} Y$.
  In the three example categories, this morphism is almost never an isomorphism.
- When it comes to monoids and Lie algebras, we also have a notion of semidirect products.
  Such a semidirect product $X ⋊_θ Y$ has a universal property that characterizes morphisms of the form $X ⋊_θ Y \to Z$.
  If the homomorphism $θ$ is trivial, then this gives us the commutative coproduct.

Comment: +1. I have written about this concept before (here in the forum, maybe also my thesis). You have already given the correct generalization of commutative coproducts of monoids. It is the special case of the Zappa Zepp product where both actions are trivial. But Lie algebras don't fall into this category. For this we need the notion of an *orthogonal* coproduct. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345501/is-a-times-b-the-same-as-a-oplus-b. I could post a full answer but to be honest I think you have more or less answered it already yourself. Or, what is really unclear to you?